# Prevent Initial Add-On Check in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, proxy

How do I **prevent** (or rather disallow) Firefox to **check for newer versions of add-ons** and themes and plug-ins **before it starts up.**
Since I am on a proxy connection, I get a dozen proxy password boxes every time I start Firefox.
This also seems to make Firefox load more slowly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Advanced

Go to the "Update" tab and where it says "Automatically check for updates to:", uncheck:

- Firefox
- Installed add-ons

Comment: Great! +1 , But now I have to check it manually every time. What I meant was that instead of doing all this before start if it could do the check some where after starting...

Comment: It will not stop you from clicking the Tools Menu -> Add-Ons and then Click the find Updates button